# Change cursor in text input field on IE 11

Tags: css, cursor, internet-explorer-11

The default cursor is a I-bar in text input field.  If I want to change it to "wait", I could do it like this:

```
<div style="cursor:wait;height:50px;width:200px;border:2px solid black;">
<input type="text" style="cursor:wait">
</div>
```

(The DIV block is for reference only and the cursor does change in the DIV block.)
It works in most browsers including IE with versions before 11.  But on IE 11, it doesn't work.  Could someone help me how to do this on IE 11?  Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to know how to do this as well. IE, why do you always have to make life difficult...

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use [a proprietary `meta` tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make new versions of IE emulate older versions. In this case, you would need to use version 8 or lower:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

This would have several other effects, too, partly undocumented, partly described in Microsoft’s documentation of IE.

It seems that IE 9 introduced a usability improvement that prevents authors messing around too much with “cursor” (pointer) shape, and you need to drop the level of IE to prevent that improvement.

Comment: I need some other features that are not supported by IE 8.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<input type="text" style="cursor:wait;" disabled="disabled">
```

That will, as you probably have guessed, disable the input field, and allow you to change the cursor type. You can enable it later, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Seems a good workaround.  But I need to change the cursor even when the users are filling the text field.  So is there any other method that can do it with the input field enabled?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand why this would need to occur. The "wait" cursor implies that an action is being performed that the user may not be able to see. In this case, it appears as though you are alerting the user of something that he or she already knows that they are doing...

Comment: Actually it is a custom cursor.  The "wait" cursor was used as an example.  Thanks.